# Angular Universal deployed to AWS Lambda using serverless not picking up js files in dist/browser

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda, serverless

I was following [this](https://medium.com/cactus-techblog/deploy-angular-universal-on-aws-lambda-from-scratch-1b169289eac2) tutorial for deploying to a lambda function. When I run it using serverless offline, it will show 404 errors for each compiled js, but when deployed it shows 403 errors for it. I checked my s3 bucket and the zipped folder has all everything needed from dist/
[live link](https://2cxrreireg.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev)
I have tried to change the base href by including `--base-href=/dev` when building. When I build and run as a SSR app, everything outputs as normal.
here is my serverless.yml:

```
service: anime-trending
plugins:
  - serverless-apigw-binary
  - serverless-offline
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  memorySize: 192
  timeout: 10
package:
  exclude:
    - ./**
  include:
    - "node_modules/aws-serverless-express/**"
    - "node_modules/@vendia/**"
    - "node_modules/binary-case/**"
    - "node_modules/type-is/**"
    - "node_modules/media-typer/**"
    - "node_modules/mime-types/**"
    - "node_modules/mime-db/**"
    - "dist/**"
    - "lambda.js"
custom:
  apigwBinary:
    types:
      - "*/*"
functions:
  api:
    handler: lambda.handler
    events:
      - http: GET /
```

my tsconfig.serverless.json:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/serverless",
    "target": "es2016",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.server.ts",
    "serverless.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "./src/app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
  }
}
```

my serverless.ts:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';
import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';
export const app = express();
const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/anime-trending/browser');
const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';
// Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModule,
}));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', distFolder);
// Example Express Rest API endpoints
// app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
// Serve static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
  maxAge: '1y'
}));
// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
});
export * from './src/main.server';
```

my dist:
[![enter image description here][1]]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8NcS.png

my main.server/ts:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

export { AppServerModule } from './app/app.server.module';
export { renderModule, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your base href arg has a very small typo.  Instead of `--base-href=/dev`,
try `--base-href=dev/`, with the prefix before the slash instead of after.   I did this for my deployment and the compiled files load correctly, but the routing within the angular app was busted horrifically.